# LibreOffice calc function to turn time string into ISO 8601 format

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a string `19 Jan 1819` and want to get it back in the ISO 8601 format
 `1819-01-19`. Is there a function in LibreOffice calc that does this conversion?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a function, it is easier to go to `Data -> Text to Columns`.  In the dialog window, select the cell to convert, then change the column type to `Date (DMY)`.

Complete instructions are at http://cca220v.net/blog.php/2012/12/20/convert-cells-from-text-to-date-libreoffice.

Comment: This seems to handle fields that don't contain months and days poorly.